# Colours within a NSArray arrayWithObjects

Tags: iphone, colors, nsarray, nsnumber

I have a simple leader boards table for an iphone game that allows me to view the previous high scores however the background is black and therefore it is not visible. I am using the code:

`[highscores addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title",[NSNumber numberWithInt:5000],nil]];`

Can I change the colour easily?

All help greatly appreciated, I expect it is simple but google is coming back with little.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: How are you setting the color in the first place?

Comment: You meant to say.. '[highscores addObject:@"whiteColor"];'
'[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor [highscores objectAtIndex:0]]];' ??

Comment: No, I just want to keep the layout I have and add an extra method if needed to implement it in white.

Comment: @David, I have just used the default text colour, I have not edited it in any way to anything other than the default.

Comment: The code you put up doesn't affect the color at all. I don't understand what you mean. Can't you change the color in the XIB or storyboard?

Comment: @Woz I have no xib or storyboard.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying!! You can simply change the background color when the particular method is called!

Comment: Did you try something like this: `[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`?

Comment: The background is and image that is constant throughout the app.

Comment: It's a `UIImage`? Then change it using: `[backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"]];`. Is that what you mean? You need to edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Look, I am only 14 and I am new to programming, I appreciate the help everyone but I dont understand to well; the pastebin is here: http://pastebin.com/ZY5VRDNK I have established that it is tied to a UILabel so in a separate method I need to make the label text white/

Comment: You want your label to have white text? If so, it's as simple as `[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]` when you instantiate the `UILabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the color is not related with an Array.Its related with the container who displays the **Title** .
you may binding the **Title** string to any UILabel.

So you have to set the **textColor** property to white.

Eg: **label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];**

Answer (score 1):

To make the UILabel white, remove this code:

```
[label1 setRGB:0 :0 :0];
```

And add do this instead:

```
[label1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Let me know if this helps you. Posting your code definitely helps. You are doing great at age 14, so keep it up.

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate it. The only thing is that I receive a warning label may not receive set text colour, is that a worry?

Comment: In your code, use `UILabel`, not `Label`. Don't you have a red squiggle under `Label`?

Comment: No but I will use UILabel now

Comment: When I use UILabal it juist returns with an error for the .position

Comment: AHHHHHH Now when I build and run the app crashes after the high scores table is suppose to display!